# Convert bitmap to PNG in-memory in C++ (win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, png

Can I convert a bitmap to PNG in memory (i.e. without writing to a file) using only the Platform SDK? (i.e. no libpng, etc.).

I also want to be able to define a transparent color (not alpha channel) for this image.

**The GdiPlus solution seems to be limited to images of width divisible by 4**. Anything else fails during the call to Save(). Does anyone know the reason for this limitation and how/whether I can work around it?

**Update: Bounty**

I'm starting a bounty (I really want this to work). I implemented the GDI+ solution, but as I said, it's limited to images with quad width. The bounty will go to anyone who can solve this width issue (without changing the image dimensions), or can offer an alternative non-GDI+ solution that works.

Comment: to get you started, i found an example to save an bitmap as png with gdi+: http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/gdi-speichern-eines-png-SID814.aspx maybe it's useful

Comment: This solution works for me, even with images where width is not divisible by 4. I'm on Windows Vista and using Visual C++ 2008.

Comment: Why don't you want to use libpng?  It has a very permissive license.

Comment: Does libpng do in-memory encoding? (or just to files?)

Comment: You can hook libpng's output using png_set_write_fn and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I've used libpng to do in-memory encoding

Comment: The quad width problem seems to be limited to older codecs that came with older versions of Windows.  I faced similar problems when on XP, but they (mostly) went away when I upgraded to Vista and then Windows 7.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I read and write PNGs using [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) and it seems to deal with everthing I throw at it (I've used it in unit-tests with things like 257x255 images and they cause no trouble).  I believe the [API](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html) is flexible enough to not be tied to file I/O (or at least you can override its default behaviour e.g see `png_set_write_fn` in section on [customization](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-5))

In practice I always use it via the much cleaner [boost::gil](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) [PNG IO extension](http://stlab.adobe.com/gil/html/group___p_n_g___i_o.html), but unfortunately that takes `char*` filenames and if you dig into it the `png_writer` and `file_mgr` classes in its implementation it seem pretty tied to `FILE*` (although if you were on Linux a version using fmemopen and in-memory buffers could probably be cooked up quite easily).

Comment: +1 thanks. May I know how to use Boost::GIL with PNG IO? I have no clue about integration and making use of that.

Comment: Boost GIL includes an "IO extension" which currently includes support for basic reading and writing to PNG files but doesn't provide enough hooks to read/write in-memory streams as the original poster was asking about.  There seems to be a new IO extension (google something like "boost GIL new IO extension" to find various postings) under development which looks like it will give a lot more flexibility in this area.

Comment: libpng, while a good solution, seems to violate the question's constraint of "using only the Platform SDK".

Comment: how do I to install this lib please? Or do I need to simply get the Source code?

Comment: @Lucie: I also struggled with finding a windows version; see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669163/whats-the-quickest-and-easiest-way-of-getting-libpng-available-for-development .  Windows development drives me bananas with this sort of stuff, compared with Linux where you can just apt-get install libpng-dev and be good to go in seconds.

Answer (score 21):

[LodePNG](https://lodev.org/lodepng/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng)) is a lib-less PNG encoder/decoder.

Answer (score 12):

On this site the code shows how convert a bitmap to PNG writing it to a file: http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/gdi-speichern-eines-png-SID814.aspx. Instead of writing to a file, the `Save` method of Bitmap also supports writing to a `IStream` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535406%28VS.85%29.aspx). You can create a Stream backed up by memory using the `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` API function. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378980%28VS.85%29.aspx). The used library, GDI+, is included in Windows up from WindowsXP, and works in Windows up from Windows98. I've never done something with it, just googled around. Looks like you can use that, though.

Comment: What about the GDI+ problem I mentioned in the original question?

Answer (score 8):

The CImage class (ATL/MFC) supports saving into PNG format. Like the GDI+ solution, it also supports saving to a stream. Here's some code I use to save it to a CByteArray:

```
CByteArray baPicture;
IStream *pStream = NULL;
if (CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &pStream) == S_OK)
{
    if (image.Save(pStream, Gdiplus::ImageFormatPNG) == S_OK)
    {
    ULARGE_INTEGER ulnSize;
        LARGE_INTEGER lnOffset;
        lnOffset.QuadPart = 0;
        if (pStream->Seek(lnOffset, STREAM_SEEK_END, &ulnSize) == S_OK)
        {
            if (pStream->Seek(lnOffset, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL) == S_OK)
            {                       
                baPicture.SetSize(ulnSize.QuadPart);
                ULONG ulBytesRead;
                pStream->Read(baPicture.GetData(), ulnSize.QuadPart, &ulBytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
pStream->Release();
```

I don't know if you'd want to use ATL or MFC, though.

Comment: Alas, there's no ATL/MFC in my project.

Comment: ok... maybe the stream save part could be useful, it should be similar to the one using GDI+

Comment: This helped me for something I was working on, +1 for that at least.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this uses libpng

Answer (score 6):

I've used GDI+ for saving a bitmap as a PNG to a file.  You should probably check out the MSDN info about GDI+ [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798(VS.85).aspx) and in particular this function [GdipSaveImageToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534041(VS.85).aspx).

This tutorial [here](http://www.mvps.org/user32/gditutorial.html) will probably provide some help as well.

Answer (score 5):

GDI's (old school, non-plus) has a `GetDIBits` method that can be asked to output bits using PNG compression (`BITMAPINFOHEADER::biCompression`  == `BI_PNG`). I wonder if this could be used to create a PNG file? Using `GetDIBits` to write standard bitmap files is complicated enough - so i suspect this would be even more difficult.

Comment: For anyone who might be thinking of going this rout, see the [answer to "GetDIBits() is failing with PNG compression"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101090/2910230), or "[JPEG and PNG Extensions for Specific Bitmap Functions and Structures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145023(VS.85).aspx)" on MSDN, that it links to.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to only use Windows APIs, [WIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719654) is the way to accomplish this, and it supports both Bitmaps and PNGs.

Comment: Are you certain it doesn't suffer from the same weird width limitation as GDI+?

Comment: No, not certain - but WIC is definitely more modern and kept up-to-date than GDI+

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be better to use a library instead of reinventing the wheel yourself.

Look into [freeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/)