# C function to convert a raw image to png

Tags: c++, c

Is there any c function that allow me to convert a raw image to a PNG file?
Preferably, I don't need to pull in a big library for that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

I do not believe so.  On the other hand, [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) isn't a huge library.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the libpng library?

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "raw image", but I've found LodePNG easy to work with. http://members.gamedev.net/lode/projects/LodePNG/ There's an example showing you how to encode some raw data to a png

Answer (score 1):

See a related question: [Convert bitmap to PNG in-memory in C++ (win32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366768/convert-bitmap-to-png-in-memory-in-c-win32)

The short answer is that GDI+ can convert a bitmap image to PNG (with some limitations), so if you're on Windows it's an option that's even more minimal than libPNG.