# Read a PNG Using Win32 / C++

Tags: windows, winapi, png

That there is no **simple** way to read a PNG file into a memory bitmap in native Windows seemed impossible, but after much googling I'm beginning to believe it. The libpng/zlib combination is just too big. Any third-party libraries Win32 libraries out there for reading a PNG?

Edit: The boost::gil::png solution is much more complex than I'd hoped, too. Just need a single call that takes a file name and fills a memory buffer with pixels.

Comment: Duplicate? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366768/convert-bitmap-to-png-in-memory-in-c-win32/538742

Comment: The core OS API should not necessarily have built in support for reading and writing multiple image types.  There are many third party libraries for this kind of thing.

Comment: Ed, I don't understand your comment in light of the fact that I was asking specifically about third-party libraries.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Or of course you could use GDI+ - The [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536316(VS.85).aspx) object takes a string constructor and loads the specified file into memory.  That way you don't need any external libraries, just that which comes with windows.

Comment: That is what I am looking for, thanks. I (mistakenly) thought that GDI+ was part of .NET, and the .NET runtime didn't go out with Windows XP and SP2. This is great news.

Comment: Nah GDI+ is a part of core Windows.

Comment: +1 I, like IJK, assumed GDI+ was .NET, and can't believe I was missing such a basic piece of knowledge. Thanks Larry!

Answer (score 1):

[libgd](http://www.libgd.org/Main_Page) is an excellent library that can be used in Windows and has bindings for many popular languages.

Answer (score 0):

There is some built-in stuff you can use: [IImgCtx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/JianImgCtxDecoder.aspx) and on later versions of windows you also have [WIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737408%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully used [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) to do this.