# Is there any way to draw a PNG image on window without using MFC?

Tags: winapi, image, png

I am developing a [Windows API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) application without using [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library).
I am using standard Windows libraries.

How do I draw a PNG image in a window?

Help me with some sample code.

I have tried some codes which are available on the Internet, but all are using MFC.

Comment: Why don't you dig into MFC source code, see how it did it?

Comment: MFC uses the Win32 API internally so there will definitely be a way to do it. Dig into the MFC class that draws the PNG and see what APIs are being called there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391541/read-a-png-using-win32-c). It offers several options which should meet your needs.

Adapted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534077(VS.85).aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;

void draw()
{
   // start up GDI+ -- only need to do this once per process at startup
   GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
   ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
   GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);


   Rect rect(20,20,50,50);
   Graphics grpx(dc);
   Image* image = new Image(L"SomePhoto.png");
   grpx.DrawImage(Img,rect);

   delete image;

   // shut down - only once per process
   GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your choices are: GDI+, WIC(Windows Imaging Component) or [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use GDI+. See [Loading and Displaying Bitmaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533830(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me. It's free of MFC and can be used straight away to draw PNG images in a window.

```
    Gdiplus::Image image(L"C:\\Logo.png") ;

    Gdiplus::Graphics* graphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromHDC(GetDC(hWnd));

    RectF ImgRect(0,0,y3/10,y3/10) ;

    Gdiplus::Status result = graphics->DrawImage(&image, ImgRect);
```

Thanks for all your support and quick response to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know PNG'coding,you can decoding it. So you can draw PNG in any way~