# GetDIBits() is failing with PNG compression

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I am trying to get the size of PNG image (Without storing into file). I am using [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183402(v=VS.85).aspx) as reference. When calling `GetDIBits()`, size of image would get updated into `bi.biSizeImage`. Everything works fine when `bi.biCompression` is BI_RGB. Then I have changed the compression mode from BI_RGB to BI_PNG; `GetDIBits()` started to fail. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145023%28VS.85%29.aspx:

"This extension is not intended as a means to supply general JPEG and PNG decompression to applications, but rather to allow applications to send JPEG- and PNG-compressed images directly to printers having hardware support for JPEG and PNG images."

using GetDIBits() with BI_PNG is not allowed.